# Meaning of golden thread

Tags: meaning

What is implied when this person says "like a golden thread"?
The whole context is as follows:

> “The Kingdom  theme runs through the Bible like a golden  thread. That
>   is so, even though about 40 men wrote the Bible. And many of them
>   lived at different times and did not know one another personally...."

Comment: It's a transparent comparison. Thread being long and thin, the implication is that the theme runs all through [in this case] the Bible without totally swamping other topics. The use of golden thread means that it is of highest value, it cannot tarnish, and though (as thread) not in-your-face, it catches the attention of anyone who can be bothered to have even a brief look.

Answer (score 1):

Gold can actually be threaded into a cloth or garment, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwork_%28embroidery%29).

Hence something especially prized running through something (like the 'Kingdom theme' through 'the Bible', as mentioned) is metaphorically like a golden thread.